# How to prove $\ln{6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=2}^{\infty}\left({1\over r^{2n}}+{2\over (r+1)^{2n}}+{1\over (r+2)^{2n}}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I need help, on how to prove

$$\ln{6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=2}^{\infty}\left({1\over r^{2n}}+{2\over (r+1)^{2n}}+{1\over (r+2)^{2n}}\right).$$

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find the announced result.

**Hint**. The double series is absolutely convergent, then one may interchange the summations, using the geometric standard evaluation,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({1\over r^{2n}}+{2\over (r+1)^{2n}}+{1\over (r+2)^{2n}}\right)=\frac{1}{2 (r-1)}+\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+2}-\frac{1}{2 (r+3)}
$$ then one may observe that terms *telescope*  to get

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=2}^{\infty}\!\left(\!{1\over r^{2n}}\!+\!{2\over (r+1)^{2n}}\!+\!{1\over (r+2)^{2n}}\!\right)\!=\!\sum_{r=2}^{\infty}\!\left(\!\frac{1}{2 (r-1)}\!-\!\frac{1}{2 (r+3)}\!+\!\frac{1}{r}\!-\!\frac{1}{r+2}\!\right)\!=\!\frac{15}8.
> $$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is the following one:
$$ \sum_{r\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{r^{2n}}+\frac{2}{(r+1)^{2n}}+\frac{1}{(r+2)^{2n}}\right) = 4(\zeta(2n)-1)-\frac{3}{2^{2n}}-\frac{1}{3^{2n}}\tag{1}$$
giving:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{r\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{r^{2n}}+\frac{2}{(r+1)^{2n}}+\frac{1}{(r+2)^{2n}}\right)=-\frac{9}{8}+4\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\zeta(2n)-1\right)\tag{2}$$
where:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\zeta(2n)-1\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}\frac{dx}{e^{2x}-e^{x}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sinh(x)}{e^{2x}-e^{x}}\,dx\tag{3} $$
and:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sinh(x)}{e^{2x}-e^{x}}\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{3x}-e^{2x}}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{x}+1}{e^{2x}}\,dx = \frac{3}{4}\tag{4} $$
leads to:

> $$ \sum_{r\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{r^{2n}}+\frac{2}{(r+1)^{2n}}+\frac{1}{(r+2)^{2n}}\right) = 3-\frac{9}{8}=\color{red}{\frac{15}{8}}\tag{5}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{r = 2}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over r^{2n}} + {2 \over \pars{r + 1}^{2n}} + {1 \over \pars{r + 2}^{2n}}}}
\\[4mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\braces{%
\sum_{r = 2}^{\infty}
\bracks{{1 \over r^{2n}} + {1 \over \pars{r + 1}^{2n}}} +
\sum_{r = 3}^{\infty}\bracks{{1 \over r^{2n}} + {1 \over \pars{r + 1}^{2n}}}}
\\[4mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over 2^{2n}} + {1 \over 3^{2n}} + 2\sum_{r = 3}^{\infty}{1 \over r^{2n}} +
2\sum_{r = 4}^{\infty}{1 \over r^{2n}}} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over 2^{2n}} + {1 \over 3^{2n - 1}} +
4\sum_{r = 4}^{\infty}{1 \over r^{2n}}}
\\[4mm] = &\
{1/4 \over 1 - 1/4} + {1/3 \over 1 - 1/9} +
4\sum_{r = 4}^{\infty}{1/r^{2} \over 1 - 1/r^{2}} =
{1 \over 3} + {3 \over 8} + 2\sum_{r = 4}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over r - 1} -
{1 \over r + 1}}
\\[4mm] = &\
{17 \over 24} +  2\
\underbrace{\sum_{r = 4}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over r - 1} - {1 \over r}}}
_{\ds{1 \over 3}}\ +\ 2\
\underbrace{\sum_{r = 4}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over r} - {1 \over r + 1}}}
_{\ds{1 \over 4}}
={17 \over 24} + 2\pars{{1 \over 3} + {1 \over 4}}
\\[4mm] = &
\color{#f00}{15 \over 8} = 1.875 \not=
\fbox{$\ds{\ \ln\pars{6} \approx 1.7918\ }$}\ !!!.
\end{align}